# Problems with vim and conque gdb plugin

Tags: python, vim, plugins, gdb

We have several development hosts, mostly red hat based. On all of them except two, I can get vim together with conque gdb running without problems. On two hosts, however, I get this when starting gdb:

```
Error detected while processing function conque_gdb#load_python:
line    6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/myuser/.vim/autoload/conque_gdb/conque_gdb.py", line 39, in <module>
    class RegisteredBpDict(collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This is on solaris 10, vim 7.4, python version 2.5.1.

I get the same on redhat 5.4 with vim 7.0 and python 2.4.3.

It works, for example on redhat 5.7 with vim 7.4 and python 2.4.3.

It seems to be something python related, but I am really completely **unfamiliar** and lost with python, so I dont know what the root cause is. On the non-working hosts I even recompiled some newer python versions (e.g. 2.7.10) but without success.

Can somebody help me to get this to work?

Comment: You should check if the module `collections` contains `MutableMapping`. Run `python` on a host that is not working and check the result of `import collections; hasattr(collections, "MutableMapping")`. If you get False, the library used by the default Python in `$PATH` does not contain the necessary dependencies you need for your plugin. For anyone else curious, the source code can be found here: [gh: vim-scripts/Conque-GDB](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-GDB/blob/master/autoload/conque_gdb/conque_gdb.py#L39)

Comment: Okay, as expected, on the non-working hosts I will get false, while on the working hosts I will get true.
Now how do I fix this? As I said, I am not familiar with python, I dont know how to fix the libraries.

Comment: Okay I have to add, on the non-working host I also have a freshly compiled python 2.7.10, which gives `true` for the above test.
However, even if I put this in my `$PATH`, I still get this error in vim, so this seems like vim/conque_gdb is **not** using the python from my path?

Comment: Okay actually I was just able to resolve this issue by recompiling vim using the newer, separately compiled version of python. 
If you add your hint as a separate answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Great, glad to hear my hint was of use! Added an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this problem is to check if the Python binary in `$PATH` actually includes the module and attribute your Vim plugin is trying to invoke.

Run `python` on a host that is not working, and check the module/attribute using `hasattr()`:

```
>>> import collections; hasattr(collections, "MutableMapping")
True
```

If the result is `False`, the library used by the Python in `$PATH` does not contain the necessary dependencies you need for your plugin.

As per discussed in the comments, this can be solved by ensuring that Python is compiled with the correct libraries, and this is the version of Python that is used by Vim.

Comment: To give some more hints, in case other people encounter this issue:
vim refused to use my separate python build, and always used the systems default. I had to supply a concrete python path for `configure` for vim to compile with this specific version, like so: `vi_cv_path_python=/pythonpath/bin/python ./configure --enable-pythoninterp`
Note that the `vi_cv_path_python` variable contains the path to the `python` **binary**.